# Remove N items from IList where match predicate

Tags: c#

I would like to remove N items from an IList collection. Here's what I've got:

```
public void RemoveSubcomponentsByTemplate(int templateID, int countToRemove)
{
    //  TaskDeviceSubcomponents is an IList
    var subcomponents = TaskDeviceSubcomponents.Where(tds => tds.TemplateID == templateID).ToList();

    if (subcomponents.Count < countToRemove)
    {
        string message = string.Format("Attempted to remove more subcomponents than found. Found: {0}, attempted: {1}", subcomponents.Count, countToRemove);
        throw new ApplicationException(message);
    }

    subcomponents.RemoveRange(0, countToRemove);
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work as advertised. TaskDeviceSubcomponents is an IList, so it doesn't have the RemoveRange method. So, I call .ToList() to instantiate an actual List, but this gives me a duplicate collection with references to the same collection items. This is no good because calling RemoveRange on subcomponents does not affect TaskDeviceSubcomponents.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I think you need to remove each item individually.  I would change your code to this:

```
public void RemoveSubcomponentsByTemplate(int templateID, int countToRemove)
{
    //  TaskDeviceSubcomponents is an IList
    var subcomponents = TaskDeviceSubcomponents
                         .Where(tds => tds.TemplateID == templateID)
                         .Take(countToRemove)
                         .ToList();

    foreach (var item in subcomponents)
    {
        TaskDeviceSubcomponents.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Note that it is important to use `ToList` here so you are not iterating `TaskDeviceSubcomponents` while removing some of its items.  This is because LINQ uses lazy evaluation, so it doesn't iterate over `TaskDeviceSubcomponents` until you iterate over `subcomponents`.

**Edit:** I neglected to only remove the number of items contained in `countToRemove`, so I added a `Take` call after the `Where`.

**Edit 2:** Specification for the Take()-Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh thanks! The .Take() was really helpful actual. :)